# Iterating though a Web Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to scrape dates from Yelp. I noticed there is the only one difference in the web elements for the dates of reviews, it is a number where I have inputted the num variable. I was hoping to assign the number to the num variable, then increase the value of variable until there is nothing else to grab. I'm still a python noob and was hoping to get an old pros help with this?

Code is down below, my thought process was that I will add the element to the array then increase it before the loop so that it doesn't match right away and break the loop.

Here is the webpage https://www.yelp.com/biz/gordon-ramsay-hells-kitchen-las-vegas-3?osq=Restaurants&sort_by=date_desc

And for clarification it is the review dates I'm interested in.

```
    def date_harvesting(self):
    self.num = []
    num = 1
    i = 0
    tester = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/yelp-react-root/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[' + str(num) + ']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span')
    self.num.append(tester.text)
    num += 1
    while i < num:
        if self.num[i] != tester.text:
            self.num.append(tester.text)
            i += 1
            num += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    print(tester)
    print(self.num)
```

Comment: Add page address

Comment: https://www.yelp.com/biz/gordon-ramsay-hells-kitchen-las-vegas-3?osq=Restaurants&sort_by=date_desc

And for clarification it is the review dates I'm interested it.

Comment: Are you aware that your indentation is inaccurate?

Comment: What is `tester`?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes! Sorry that got messed up when I pasted the code over. Like I said I'm a noob haha.

Comment: @vitaliis tester is just the variable name I gave it. It holds the xpath for the date.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial thought for creating array is correct.
But, while loop in this case adds more complexity, as for me.
If you want just to get all elements use `for` loop.
I've tested the example below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/gordon-ramsay-hells-kitchen-las-vegas-3?osq=Restaurants&sort_by=date_desc')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".review__373c0__13kpL.border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT")))
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".review__373c0__13kpL.border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT")
reviews = []
for card in cards:
    date = card.find_element_by_css_selector(".margin-t1__373c0__oLmO6.margin-b1-5__373c0__2Wblx.border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT").text
    feedback = card.find_element_by_css_selector(".margin-b2__373c0__abANL.border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT>p>span").text
    reviews.append([date, feedback])
for i in reviews:
    print(i)
```

The result is the list of feedback and review dates:

```
['5/2/2021', "Hell's Kitchen definitely lived up to its reputation! Every single dish was exceptionally cooked and perfectly seasoned. While the hostess was quite snotty and rude upon check in until she realized we DID have a reservation, this unacceptable welcome was overshadowed by exquisite food and a wonderful, attentive waiter who made great recommendations and enhanced our dining experience tenfold. Already making plans to dine here again during our next trip to Vegas.\n\nFor appetizers I had:\n* Lobster Risotto (5/5!! And I dislike the texture of risotto)\n* Pan Seared Scallops (4/5 but not a huge scallop fan)\n\nMain courses and sides I had:\n* Beef Wellington (5/5)\n* Braised Short Rib (5/5)\n* Filet Mignon (I didn't try this)\n* Baked Mac & Cheese (5/5)\n* Potato purée (5/5 so delicious and creamy)\n* Roasted asparagus (5/5)\n\nDesserts I had:\n* sticky toffee pudding  (5/5 highly recommend)\n* salted peanut decadence (5/5 I love peanuts so this was my favorite)\n* chocolate sin cake (4/5 delicious, a bit too rich for my personal taste)\n* coconut 3-ways (5/5 this was the most surprising at how delicious it was, and definitely the favorite of the others at the table)"]
['5/2/2021', "A must dine experience when in Vegas!\n\nWe've been to Gordon Ramsey's steak and although we thought the food there was excellent, this places beats it by a whole notch. The beef Wellington was flaky, crispy on the outside and soft and tender in the middle-- I mean, how do they do it?! Also, they seemed to have gotten their welly down much better than at GRSteak.\n\nScallops were the most perfectly cooked scallops. Salmon was fresh and perfectly crispy. I mean everything was Divinely delicious from start to finish!\n\nService was AMAZING!\n\nMake reservations now. We couldn't get in last time and made reservations 6 weeks out.\n\nSo goood, and so worth the $$$$\n\nDefinite highlight of our trip!!"]
['5/1/2021', 'Food was good, but for the prices of everything i expected a lot more from here. I was a little disappointed but it was okay. Staff were great though! Everyone was very nice and pleasant!']
['5/1/2021', "This is a good spot for a nice dinner, and I would say you at least have to go once while you're in Vegas. We did have a bad experience with the reservation because they cancelled it without notifying us. When we showed up to the restaurant, the staff was very rude, and they told us we would just have to make a new reservation for a different day. Luckily, we still had a few days left in Vegas, and we were able to reserve a table for the next evening. When we arrived, the staff at the front was still rude, but our waiter was excellent! He recommended what dishes we should try, and they were very good! The food is definitely very unique. However, Gordon Ramsay's famous dish, the Beef Wellington, was pretty average. The rest of the food was phenomenal though! The side dishes were served family style. Also, the drink called, Notes from Gordon, is amazing, and I would for sure recommend! Overall, it's worth it to at least go to the restaurant once for the experience and unique food!"]
['5/1/2021', "First impression, very hard to make a reservation, then we arrived ontime just to be told to wait 15-20 min for a table. Host did not introduce herself just sent us to our table, didn't ask what seating we would prefer. Had to ask to be seated by the window.\n\nFood is overpriced, we ordered the 3 course dinner $80 but its beef Wellington ONLY, hopefully we can have an option for Prime Rib or Tomahawk Ribeye. The beef Wellington was tender but didn't have that WOW factor, Cesar Salad was plain they didnt even offer parmesan or cracked pepper. Desert bread pudding was the best part of the meal but  I felt like we just ate at Black Agus restaurant with poor service. This is basically a 3 star restaurant with over priced food. Gordon Ramsey i had high hopes in your establishments"]
['4/30/2021', "Not very impressed.  Have been to Gordon Ramsay Steak twice and thought it was expensive, but definitely worth the money.  I thought this place was just very expensive and the food was in no way worth it.  And I have been to a lot of the nice places in town including Michael's at the South Point, The Steakhouse at Circus Circus, Hanks at Green Valley, just to name a few."]
['4/30/2021', "We came for lunch to celebrate mine and my dad's birthdays. I had the fixed lunch with the beef Wellington with Caesar's salad and the banana pudding. The cocktail called A Note from Gordon was very tasty.  The beer Wellington was cooked perfectly and the salad was a healthy portion. The service was impeccable. Definitely worth the money and the waiter was extremely friendly."]
['4/29/2021', 'Wow the servers are amazing! Great drinks and good presentation. Place really holds up . We heard all the hype but this place seems for real ! A must try !']
['4/29/2021', "It's Gordon so you expected it to be great! And it is. Basic but delicious and vegan friendly!! Yay!"]
['4/29/2021', "Hell's Kitchen was, in a word, fantastic! They are located OUTSIDE of  Caesar's Palace on the Las Vegas Strip.\n\nFirst off, they have replicated the show to an almost exact replica. The chefs are even wearing team colors-- red or blue!\n\nThe do require a reservation for tables, however we were able to secure a couple seats at the bar for full service.\n\nI had a three course meal package. I started with seared sea scallops, pea purée, and a reduction. For my main course, I ordered the Beef Wellington with potato mash, root vegetables and a red wine reduction. For dessert, we had the Sticky Toffee pudding.\n\nEverything was so flavorful and cooked to perfection! Definitely worth the high price tag! Check them out the next time you come to Vegas."]
```